# Deploy App on Azure portal

Tags: java, azure, portal, azure-deployment

Now i want to deploy my java aplication into azure cloud use Azure portal.

1. First, I create new hosting service
2. Then I fill some information into form and try upload Windows Azure Package and Service Configuration File from locally computer.

But when I click Ok button, I got error message like below:

> Warning: This deployment has at least one role with only one instance.
>   We recommend that you deploy at least two instances per role to ensure
>   high availability in case one of the instances becomes unavailable.
>   Doing so also enables coverage of the Windows Azure Compute SLA, which
>   guarantees 99.95% uptime. For more information please visit here. 
>   Find more solutions in the Windows Azure support forum.
>
> Error: The deployment requires certificates that do not exist for the
>   new hosted service.  To fix, create the new hosted service without the
>   deployment, add the required certificate(s), and then create the
>   deployment.  Find more solutions in the Windows Azure support forum.

What is this error?

Answer (score 2):

Did you enable remote desktop, or create an SSL endpoint? If so, you need to upload those certificates. To do that, create the hosted service without deploying. Then upload your cert to the Certificates folder under the hosted service name. Detailed instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg465712.aspx).

You can ignore the warning, as you're just learning and not deploying in a production enrivornment, but it's telling you that Windows Azure's Compute SLA only kicks in when having two or more instances.

Comment: Now i can create new hosting service after i add work role.But when upload is on progress.it always timeout when progress about 60%, i have try almost 3 times.It's still same.Is there another trick to upload these file in Windows Azure Portal ?

Comment: I rarely upload through the portal. I tend to upload with a separate tool (I use Cerebrata's Cloud Storage Studio), as they are optimized to upload parallel streams. There are some free ones, like the one from [CloudBerry](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/free-microsoft-azure-explorer.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.I have upload my cscfg and cspkg file using Azure Storage Explorer and it's very helpfull.i don't get timeout again :)

Now my simple jsp app already running on http://0c14bf7fe3cc439daaba409d4520372a.cloudapp.net/Achilles/

Thanks for all